# How to access the elements wrapped inside a ".lazyload-wrapper" using Selenium and C#?

Tags: c#, selenium, automated-tests, lazy-loading

I am building a testing tool for a popular hardware shop website in Australia. I want my test to go to a page that contains, let's say for example, 36 results (The page actually says "Showing 36 of 151 results") and click in the "add to cart" button in one randomly chosen product. To do this I am trying with `driver.FindElements`  to capture all the 36 buttons in the page using a CssSelector.
The problem I am facing is that i can only get the first 12 items because the rest 24 are wrapped in a `class=lazyload-wrapper` and I just can't get the driver to capture them.
I have tried scrolling the page to the bottom, I have tried inserting Thread.Sleep everywhere, I have tried with `WebDriverWait`, I have also recreated some deprecated functions from ExpectedConditions to make it work but I am still only getting 12 elements.
I have read pretty much all of the posts about similar issues here and in other forums but I am still stuck with the same 12 items. Perhaps Selenium is not the best choice to do this. If anyone can throw some light with on this challenge it will be greatly appreciated.
This is the class I am using to interact with the page, please forgive me for leaving all that commented out code, it's just to show all the failed attempts:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;

namespace Model.Pages
{
    public class CarAccessoriesPage : BasePage
    {
        public CarAccessoriesPage(IWebDriver driver) : base(driver)
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Add a random product to the shopping cart.
        /// </summary>
        public CarAccessoriesPage AddRandomItemToCart()
        {
            // smooth scrolling down to force loading did not work
            // IJavaScriptExecutor jsex = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
            // jsex.ExecuteScript("window.scrollTo({left:0, top:document.body.scrollHeight, behavior:'smooth'});");

            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

            // Scroll
            IJavaScriptExecutor jsex = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
            jsex.ExecuteScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);");

            // maybe wait for the page to load? Did not work.
            wait.Until(d => ((IJavaScriptExecutor)d).ExecuteScript("return document.readyState").Equals("complete"));
            
            // Maybe inserting an ugly pause... no bueno
            Thread.Sleep(3000);

            // driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[data-index='35']")); // this element is not found

            Random r = new Random();
            int i = r.Next(0, GetPartialResultsCount());

            // First approach throws OutOfRangeException because only 12 elements are found
            // IWebElement itemElement = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
            //     .Until(d => d.FindElements(By.CssSelector("[data-locator='atcButton']")))[i];

            // Implementing a function from ExpectedConditions deprecated in C#, no good enough
            var elements = wait
                .Until(PresenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.CssSelector("[data-locator='atcButton']")));

            // maybe trying access the article elements inside the wrapper... fail
            // var elements = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("article.lazyload-wrapper "));

            Console.WriteLine(elements.Count); // Always 12!!! I know there are better ways to log

            IWebElement ranItem = elements[i]; // Throws an OutOfRangeException if i > 11
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            // center the element so the tob and bottom banners don intercept the click
            jsex.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView({block: 'center'});", ranItem);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            ranItem.Click();

            Thread.Sleep(1000); // important or last function in test does not work (assertion fails: expected != actual)
            return this;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get the number of items in the shopping cart.
        /// </summary>
        public int GetCartCount()
        {
            return Int32.Parse(driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("cartItemCount")).Text);
        }


        private Func<IWebDriver, ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement>> PresenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By locator)
        {
            return (driver) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    var elements = driver.FindElements(locator);
                    return elements.Any() ? elements : null;
                }
                catch (StaleElementReferenceException)
                {
                    return null;
                }
            };
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Generate a random int no larger than the Collection of products
        /// in the page. But due to lazy loading, the number generated was causing an out of range exception.
        /// </summary>
        private int GetPartialResultsCount()
        {
            string partialResultsCount = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".resultsCount > p")).Text;
            return Int32.Parse(Regex.Match(partialResultsCount, @"\d+").Value);
        }

    }
}
```

The test itself is actually very straight forward:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using Model.Pages;

namespace Tests
{
    public class ShoppingCartTests : BaseTests
    {

        [Test]
        public void ValidateCartItemsCount()
        {
            int cartCount = open<HomePage>()
                .GoToCarAccessoriesPage()
                .AddRandomItemToCart()
                .AddRandomItemToCart()
                .GetCartCount();

            // Validate cart has 2 items
            Assert.AreEqual(2, cartCount);
        }
    }
}
```

Finally I just probably need to mention that the test will run and work if I only consider 12 items, but it has become like a personal obsession to get all the items that a user could see in the page. Also, no sure if I should share the actual website I am testing or this goes against the community rules or best practice. Probably is enough to say that is the most popular hardware shop in Australia and the website is fairly complex.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you share the url?

Comment: I have something like this on a site. What I ended up doing was this. Do a loop with a bool to see if the element exists. If it does you should be fine to click. If not click the load more button and keep clicking until you either find the item or you can't click load more any more. Would something like this work for you?

Comment: Sure JD308: "https://www.bunnings.com.au/products/tools/automotive-tools/car-accessories"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe find the wrapped elements using an xpath selector like

```
"//*[contains(@class, 'lazyload-wrapper')]//button[contains(@data-locator, 'atcButton')]"
```

And then add the result to the one you usually get?

Comment: Thanks but I am not looking for the 'cartItemCount', I think you are proposing to use xpath to get the elements inside the div with class 'lazyload-wrapper'. I already tried that with this line: `var els = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@class='lazyload-wrapper']/button[@data-locator='atcButton']"));` and it doesn't work, the return collection has a count = 0. If you want to take a look at the page I am working with go to this site: link and look for this element `<div class="lazyload-wrapper">`.

Comment: You missed a slash in the xpath. Updated my answer to the relevant one, sorry.

I went to the website in my javascript selenium project, and just doing an
  

`await driver.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);");    const actbuttons = await driver.findElements(By.xpath("//button[contains(@data-locator, 'atcButton')]"));` 

returned me 36 elements. You are in C#, sadly, so maybe there is some language weirdness

Comment: I found a weird fix by adding pauses and scrolling twice, it is a very brittle test but at least is working and returning 36 elements. I am avoiding xpath because in my organisation they don't like to use it in this context, so I am trying to stick to the CSS selectors. Yes, I agree, javascript would probably be more appropriate to deal with these asynchronicities. Thanks for commenting.

Answer (score 0):

So, after many tries I found a way to make the test work and capture the elements wrapped in the lazyloader div. It's not very elegant and I am not exactly sure why do I need to scroll twice to the browser to actually perform the scrolling, and also I am not sure why the elements go missing if I remove one the pauses. By the way, the pauses I am using are simple Thread.Sleep(1000) wrapped in a helper class. Here is the code:

```
using System;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Model.Helpers;

namespace Model.Pages
{
    public class CarAccessoriesPage : BasePage
    {
        public CarAccessoriesPage(IWebDriver driver) : base(driver)
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Add a random product to the shopping cart.
        /// </summary>
        public CarAccessoriesPage AddRandomItemToCart()
        {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
            IJavaScriptExecutor jsex = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
            Random r = new Random();

            // Wait for the page to load.
            wait.Until(d => ((IJavaScriptExecutor)d).ExecuteScript("return document.readyState").Equals("complete"));

            // Scroll
            jsex.ExecuteScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);");

            // Slow down
            BrowserHelper.Pause();

            // Scroll again
            jsex.ExecuteScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);");

            // Brake
            BrowserHelper.Pause();

            // Get all the 'add to cart' button elements
            var elements = wait
                .Until(PresenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.CssSelector("[data-locator='atcButton']")));

            // Test output
            Trace.WriteLine($"Total products found: {elements.Count}");

            // Select a random item
            IWebElement ranItem = elements[r.Next(0, elements.Count)];

            // Brake
            BrowserHelper.Pause();

            // Center the element so the top and bottom banners don't intercept the click
            jsex.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView({block: 'center'});", ranItem);

            // Brake a little 
            BrowserHelper.Pause();

            // Click 'add to cart'
            ranItem.Click();

            // Brake again. Important or last function in test does not work (assertion fails: expected != actual)
            BrowserHelper.Pause(); 

            return this;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get the number of items in the shopping cart.
        /// </summary>
        public int GetCartCount()
        {
            return Int32.Parse(driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("cartItemCount")).Text);
        }


        private Func<IWebDriver, ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement>> PresenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By locator)
        {
            return (driver) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    var elements = driver.FindElements(locator);
                    return elements.Any() ? elements : null;
                }
                catch (StaleElementReferenceException)
                {
                    return null;
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```